# Field of table as GET argument

Tags: php, html, href

I'm developing a small project in which I use a loop to display all the contents of a database table in an HTML table. For each row I need a clickable button that, if pressed , can "remember" the ID of the table's element to witch it corresponds. I've some problem with the href of the link. That's my code:

```
<td>
    <a href="modifica.php?id=<?php echo $row[ ' ID ']  ?> " class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="small material-icons right">mode_edit</i></a>
</td>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<td>                 
    <a href="modifica.php?id='<?php echo $row[ ' ID ']  ?> ' " class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="small material-icons right">mode_edit</i></a>
</td>
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting any $_GET variable name in your `href` attribute.

Try replacing

```
<a href="modifica.php?=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="small material-icons right">mode_edit</i></a>
```

By

```
<a href="modifica.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="small material-icons right">mode_edit</i></a>
```

Basically, I've added **id** between the **?=**. And removed the space in your `$row[' ID ']`

```
modifica.php?id=
```

Instead of

```
modifica.php?=
```

I've removed the space in the index of the $row variable because `$row[' ID ']` is not the same as `$row['ID']`.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right thanks! I've also forgotten a ; at the end of the PHP statement(but I think it is not required). A question: why is it different with the spaces?

Comment: @LuigiCerone Because the space is inside the quotes, therefore it's included in the index name, which is a string. If you want to have a space, you can put it outside the quotes. `$row[ 'id' ]` is the same as `$row['id']` because the space is not included in the string. It's the same logic as why "Apple" and "Apple   " is not the same string.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the spaces within the square brackets and add a name to the GET variable, it would look like this:

```
<td>
<a href="modifica.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']  ?> " class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="small material-icons right">mode_edit</i></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
$row[ ' ID ']
```

use

```
$row['ID']
```

you have spaces before and after ID text, fix that please